# Change flex-direction for mobile layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 divs (A, B, C) where A is positioned at left and BC are positioned at right.
[![pic 1][1]][1]
But for mobile layout I want to have them positioned like the image below...where C is positioned at left and AB are at right
[![pic 2][2]][2]

for the first pic I had this code implemented

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .container {
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">A</div>
 <div class="container">
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

But for mobile devices I tried using `flex-direction` but it isn't giving me the expected output. any suggestions?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nhZi.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyeQA.png

Comment: It produce the expected result for having 2 nested `.container`

Comment: yes but I want the result to be like the pic 2...How do I change the html/css so that pic 1 and pic 2 both conditions are satisfied?

Comment: Are you allowed to change the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be possible with the extra container for B and C which you have in there, but if you put all three elements on the same level, you can use the `order` parameter to determine the order of the flex items and `margin-right: auto;` to do the left/right alignment, and all this differently in the media query as shown below.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.A {
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .A {
    order: 2;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .B {
    order: 3;
  }
  .C {
    order: 1;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
</div>
```